# Jboss Seam Mail 2.2.1: m:message recognized as UIInstructions

Tags: seam2

I'm trying to run Jboss Seam Mail example from here http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.Final/reference/en-US/html/mail.html

The mail isn't sent and there's no error in the log.

Using Eclipse debugger I detected that m:message tag from the template is recognized as com.sun.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions object and not as org.jboss.seam.mail.ui.UIMessage object.

I don't understand why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

As it appeared I used example from this http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/mail.html

And there's difference in xmlns

In 2.2.1 we have: xmlns:m="http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail"

and in 2.3.0 there's: xmlns:m="http://jboss.org/schema/seam/mail"

That was my problem.